# I want to give an exception to the first character in inputType of editText with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-edittext

I want to make sure that the filter does not apply only the first letter in the numberPassword of the editText. Please give me an answer on what to do.

```
android:inputType="numberPassword"
```

ex -******* -> -3******

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you need to add a custom filter.

```
import android.text.InputFilter
import android.text.Spanned
import java.util.regex.Matcher
import java.util.regex.Pattern


class RegexInputFilter(pattern: Pattern?) : InputFilter {
    private var mPattern: Pattern? = null

    /**
     * Convenience constructor, builds Pattern object from a String
     * @param pattern Regex string to build pattern from.
     */
    constructor(pattern: String?) : this(Pattern.compile(pattern)) {}

    override fun filter(
        source: CharSequence, start: Int, end: Int,
        dest: Spanned, dstart: Int, dend: Int
    ): CharSequence? {
        val matcher: Matcher = mPattern.matcher(source)
        return if (!matcher.matches()) {
            ""
        } else null
    }

    init {
        mPattern = pattern
    }
}
```

set this filter to edit text by passing your required pattern in the constructor as below

```
    editText.setFilters(InputFilter[] {
    RegexInputFilter("[A-Za-z]"),
    InputFilter.LengthFilter(10)
})
```